# If Array is Nothing, then ignore and move on to the next one in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to dynamically filter an OLAP pivot table. Depending on whether the user checks the box for a certain month or not, it will filter the pivot accordingly. Several boxes can be checked (several months). Ex: If they check April and June, the OLAP pivot table will be filtered to April and June. Here is my code:

```
Dim Apr18 As String
Dim May18 As String
Dim Jun18 As String

    If Workbooks("A").Sheets("FilePath").CheckApr.Value = True Then
    Apr18 = "[Calendar].[Date Hierarchy].[Year].&[2018].&[April]"
    End If
    If Workbooks("A").Sheets("FilePath").CheckMay.Value = True Then
    May18 = "[Calendar].[Date Hierarchy].[Year].&[2018].&[May]"
    End If
    If Workbooks("A").Sheets("FilePath").CheckJun.Value = True Then
    Jun18 = "[Calendar].[Date Hierarchy].[Year].&[2018].&[June]"
    End If

    Workbooks("B").SlicerCaches("Slicer_Date_Hierarchy") _
    .VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array(Apr18, May18, Jun18)
```

When all the months are checked, the code works fine. However, I am struggling to find a solution for whenever a user chooses April and June, but not May. In this case, the Array should be:

```
Workbooks("B").SlicerCaches("Slicer_Date_Hierarchy") _ 
.VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array(Apr18, Jun18)
```

How do I change the code so that if a checkbox is unchecked, to ignore that field? Doing

```
 ELse
 Apr18 = ""
```

Doesn't work.

Note: I have 12 months

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would need to build an array as you go (arr in example), similar to (untested):

```
dim arr as variant
Dim Apr18 As String, May18 As String, Jun18 As String
'
redim arr(0)
If Workbooks("A").Sheets("FilePath").CheckApr.Value = True Then
    if not arr(ubound(arr)) = "" then redim preserve arr(ubound(arr)+1) 'redimensions the array to be +1 size larger, preserviing previous data
    arr(ubound(arr)) = "[Calendar].[Date Hierarchy].[Year].&[2018].&[April]" 'put into array
End If
'add other items
Workbooks("B").SlicerCaches("Slicer_Date_Hierarchy") _
.VisibleSlicerItemsList = arr 'use array you generated
```

---

**Edit1:**

Changing this up a little to help account for your 12 months:

```
dim arr as variant, brr as variant, crr as variant, i as long
brr = array("CheckJan","CheckFeb","CheckMar","CheckApr","CheckMay") 'etc...
crr = array("January","February","March","April","May") 'etc...
redim arr(0)
For i = lbound(brr) to ubound(brr) 'ensure brr and crr are the same length
    If Workbooks("A").Sheets("FilePath").CheckBoxes(brr(i)).Value = True Then
        if not arr(ubound(arr)) = "" then redim preserve arr(ubound(arr)+1) 'redimensions the array to be +1 size larger, preserviing previous data
        arr(ubound(arr)) = "[Calendar].[Date Hierarchy].[Year].&[2018].&[" & crr(i) & "]" 'put into array
    End If
next i
Workbooks("B").SlicerCaches("Slicer_Date_Hierarchy").VisibleSlicerItemsList = arr 'use array you generated
```

Comment: It gives me Application-defined or object-defined error on the last line

Comment: @Jade just on the use of `arr` to determine the slicers?  seems like you would have had a similar error in your example code, unless something didn't get added to the array (you may need to verify that the names went in as expected using `Debug.Print` for each element of the array...

Comment: I tried the Edit1 code and now it gives me an error on the .Checkboxes(brr(i)) line, "Unable to get Checkboxes property of the worksheet class"... How do I use the Debug.Print for each element?

Comment: @Jade just using the code outright could be an issue, as several changes may need made.  In the **Edit1** code, i made the assumption you were using CheckBoxes with names CheckJan, etc., which may not be appropriate; that was primarily how to give the example as a loop to save on a bunch of additional lines of code.  *Focusing on your previous comment and `Debub.Print`*, in your code, you would add something like `For i = lbound(arr) to ubound(arr)` then `debug.print arr(i)` and you should see the value in the `Immediate Window`.  That will allow you to see if format is correct.

Comment: @Jade If possible, let's focus on the first set of code so we can handle your error around the 1004 error.  Was the error on the destination side or was the use of `arr` the problem?

Comment: I tested the first code again, and now it is working. As for your previous reply, the Checkboxes names I am using are indeed CheckJan, CheckFeb, etc.

Comment: I am copying/pasting your code and changing the month name of every month and it is working. Thank you! Not sure why it wasn't working the first time around.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using `Split` to create the array from a string (which you can build up)?  An somewhat  ugly example:

```
Dim list As String
list = list & "|abc"
list = list & "|def"
Dim arr As Variant: arr = Split(Mid(list, 2), "|")  ' assumes list non-empty; ignore first char (delimiter)

Debug.Print arr(0)
Debug.Print arr(1)
```